# How to calculate eigen vectors in matlab without eig

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a matrix, I need to get the eigenvectors. I already calculated the eigenvalues,  Let's assume we have the eigenvalues, I wrote  this

```
  for i = 1:length(c)
  syms y
  cal_vec = (c-eig_Val(i)*I)*y == 0;
  eigVec(:,i) = double(solve(cal_vec,y));
end
```

now I got zero as y, but I need to get y 1 and y2

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is [`null`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html), i.e., calculate the null-space of `c-eig_Val(i)*I`.

Be aware that it won't work out-of-the-box if you have eigenvalues with multiple eigenvectors, or if your eigenvalues are not (sufficiently) accurate.

Comment: how can I calculate the null space